# bundle exec not working in Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exec, bundle, redmine

I am following the [Redmine Install Tutorial](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall/%22Redmine%20Install%20Tutorial%22)

on step 5 it says

> Step 5 - Session store secret generation
>   This step generates a random key used by Rails to encode cookies storing session data thus preventing their tampering.
>   Generating a new secret token invalidates all existing sessions after restart.

```
bundle exec rake generate_secret_token
```

I'm on Windows 10. When I try to do bundle exec in CMD, I get cannot find the path specified. For whatever reason I cannot find any reference to this problem (perhaps I'm not searching for the right terms). I can't imagine I'm the first to experience this but in any case, how can I resolve it? I can check ruby version, gem version, and rails version just fine. I've been able to do steps 1-4 fine so I don't get why I can't run bundle exec. I suppose this is implied but I can't do step 6 either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have rake rubygem installed? Try to run this in CMD:

```
gem install rake
```

Then run the command again:

```
bundle exec rake generate_secret_token
```

I'm looking at this: [source](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/495)

Comment: My goodness that was it. I guess because I don't have too much experience in Rails but I would think that I would get an error about "bundle exec". If I had an error saying something about rake that would have pointed me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: If you've got previous experience in PHP, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462969/php-composer-compared-with-ruby-gems-and-bundler) helped me put into perspective how tools in Rails like Bundler and RubyGems compared and contrasted to their PHP counterparts some time ago. Pretty good read if you're just starting out in Rails. Glad to have helped.