# Redmine on Windows - error rake generate_secret_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I am trying to follow the Redmine guide [here](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall). 
I am running into the same problem this previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43883489/bundle-exec-not-working-in-windows/43883541#43883541), but the solution didn't solve it for me.

Steps that I have done so far:

**Ruby**

I have downloaded/installed the Ruby from http://rubyinstaller.org and verified that Rails was installed.

*rails -v*

> Rails 5.1.3

*ruby -v*

> ruby 2.3.3p222

**MySQL**

Visual Studio 2019 redistributable installed.

Ran the MySql installer msi
Selected the Developer (Defaults)

Took all the defaults for the rest of the wizard (I did set root password and added a user)

*I think I had to do all this first before starting the Installation procedures.

**Redmine**

Completed step 1-4 with the MySQL settings

*Step 5*

Running the command:

*bundle exec rake generate_secret_token*

> Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory

I have verified that rake is installed

*rake -V*

> rake, version 13.0.1

*gem list rake*

> (rake 13.0.1)

Using the stackoverflow post from above, I did update the version of rake I had installed, but that didn't solve the issue. I am new to gem/bundle type of installs, so I may be missing something that is quite obvious.

Do I need to be a specific directory when running these commands?

Any direction for me would be good. I am trying to run this on a Windows Server if that makes any difference.

Comment: You probably need to be in a directory with an existing Rails app if you want to run `rake generate_secret_token` though I'm not familiar with that particular rake task. It could be an ancient Rails 4 thing that I can't remember, though.

Comment: I tried running the command the above highlighted command in the Ruby's bin directory. The command line response is: rake aborted. No Rakefile found

Comment: I made a mistake on what I documented above, I ran a Rails installer 2.3 from railsinstaller.org. I should have ran the Rubyinstaller from the rubyinstaller.org. The Ruby I had installed needs to be newer than 5.2

Comment: It doesn't matter if you manually installed Rails or not. Rails will be only be installed and usable when you run `bundle install` inside the Redmine app directory from [step 4](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall#Step-4-Dependencies-installation). Also _The Ruby I had installed needs to be newer than 5.2_ doesn't make any sense as the most recent version of Ruby is 2.7. You're confusing Ruby and Rails versions and your comments are making the issue you're having less clear. Please verify the information you share before posting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redmine is a Rails app. You must download the app, extract it, then change into that directory before running your rake task. The process for this is defined in [step 1](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall#Step-1-Redmine-application):

> Get the Redmine source code by either downloading a packaged release or checking out the code repository.
>
> See the [download page](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Download) for details.

Afterwards, you can run `bundle exec rake generate_secret_token` because that is a Rake task defined by [`lib/tasks/initializers.rake`](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/3b55f654077dfb7b4764eafa52579a83bd22152f/lib/tasks/initializers.rake#L24). Rake tasks in Rails are typically defined within the `lib/tasks` directory and you can see multiple examples there.

If you attempt to run `rake something` then Rake is going to look for a Rakefile where this task is defined. Since you're currently just in your Ruby `bin/` directory there are no defined rake tasks so you get the errors that you see.

Comment: I 'think' step 1 was completed. I have the source downloaded and extracted. I don't think there was anything else necessary after that?

Comment: I've pointed this out three different times now: **you must change into the Redmine directory after extracting it and before running any commands**, e.g., `cd redmine-4.1.0`.

Comment: I have ran the command in the redmine directory

Could not find gem 'rails (= 5.2.4.1) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Comment: This is the second time that I'm pointing out [step 4](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall#Step-4-Dependencies-installation) -- _Rails will be only be installed and usable when you run `bundle install` inside the Redmine app directory._ I suggest you try reading the documentation carefully and noting all of the steps that you are repeatedly skipping.

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance. I'm tryinh to learn this, still new to this. The information on the guide for step one says to download or checkout. I didn't realize I should run the bundle install in the redmine directory until you pointed that out. After running the "bundle install" in the redmine directory and also the subsequent steps; the rake generate_secrete_token completes.